# Python 2.7.2 IDLE shell not working

Tags: python-2.7, python-idle

For some reason the python 2.7.2 IDLE shell is not opening. I get an error that says:

*"IDLE can't bind to a TCP/IP port, which is necessary to communicate with its Python execution server. This might be because no networking is installed on this computer. Run IDLE with the -n command line switch to start without a subprocess and refer to HELP/IDLE Help 'Running without a subprocess' for further details."*

It was working fine the day before and I can't think of any changes I have made to the computer*(windows 7) that could have caused it to stop working. I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling it but it still has the same problem. I have added it to the exceptions on my firewall but nothing helps it.

Any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See a similar problem with solution here:-
http://www.cs.ucsb.edu/~pconrad/cs8/topics/idle/

If you think port number 8833 might be used by some other process, check that by giving this in command prompt:-

```
netstat -aon | find "8833"
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I tried typing netstat -aon | find "8833" into the command prompt but nothing happened. Does that mean it isn't used by another process?

Comment: if nothing was displayed, then the port is probably free. I assumed the port number is 8833.
In the error message, was some other port number mentioned? or was it just "IDLE can't bind to a TCP/IP port"?

Comment: It was just "IDLE can't bind to a TCP/IP port"

Comment: type following in command line:-
    `idle.py -n`
or if path is not set:-
    `<python_home>\lib\idlelib\idle.py -n`

Comment: I just get syntax errors when I type in <python_home>\lib\idlelib\idle.py -n or idle.py -n.

Comment: I found out this may be a bug in python and there is a patch on the python website. Do you know what I would do about applying the patch? :/

Comment: yeah, i found that too, but i have not yet tried my hand at applying patches..sorry about that..:/
I'll keep looking, will post if I find something useful. Forgive my ignorance.

Comment: For some reason it has started working again! It asked to access the internet and I said yes(I'm pretty sure it was already allowed to) and now it works fine. :) Thanks for the help and sorry if I wasted your time.

Comment: Cool! :) It was never a waste of time. By the way, if you do get the answer, could you please post it as a reply to your own question here? :)

Answer (score 1):

There I see 2 possible problems:

1. The port is used by other process, how told [vaisakh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1200132/vaisakh).
2. In your case don't show the specific port, can be the network interface is not up. Review your 'interfaces' file and be sure lo is up

Run:

```
sudo ifconfig
```

if there isn't lo, then

```
sudo ifconfig lo up
```

Comment: Sorry, I read again and see you asked about Windows, however I let the answer for if can help to somebody more (I got the same problem today with Debian :) )

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you need to do is locate your python on your computer by right clicking on it and clicking properties. After that go into your file folder and follow the path that the property finder told you, then find something that looks like this:

`C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Lib\idlelibCidle.pyw`

Don't copy this because it's the path to python on my computer, but make sure your line looks similar at the end of my line.  Copy the line that looks similar to the one above and paste it or write in the command prompt and then press space and add the `-n` to it and hit enter.  Don't add the `C:` at the beginning if it is already written in the command prompt, but make sure you add the `\`

Comment: sorry but i forgot to mention, your going to have to repeat all the those steps  for every time you want to run python correctly, sucks, i know.