# Python 3.5 Port Binding Error

Tags: python

I need some help. Im trying to run Python IDLE on my computer but I get the following error:

> IDLE can't bind to a TCP/IP port, which is necessary to communicate with its Python execution server. This might be because no networking is installed on this computer. Run IDLE with the -n command line switch to start without a subprocess and refer Help/IDLE Help 'Running without a subprocess' for further details.

My networking card just fried a couple days ago so I think this might be the problem, I dont know. I also tried refer to IDLE Help but I couldn't understand a thing.

Is there anyway I can get by this problem. I need this program operational for my programming class' a least until my new computer arrives.

Comment: Are you posting this from your computer? Do you have internet connection? Do you have Administrator privileges? Does IDLE execute basic Python scripts? Have you tried running your script from cmd.exe using `python.exe myscript.py` ?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you're using 3.5? 3.4.3 is the latest stable version, 3.5 is still in alpha testing, and may have issues.

Comment: No. Im posting this from secondary source (meaning my schools library computer). I do not have administrator privileges on this computer. On my laptop, where this problem is occurring, I do not have internet access. I have administrator privileges on my laptop.

Comment: No. Since this was the latest version I ugraded. I degrade if I have to. I also tried running 3.4.3 but I got the same problem.

Comment: Did you see [Python 2.7.2 IDLE shell not working](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9477214)? Or [port binding error, on Python opening](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16733518)?

Comment: @DKWGD15269, how can you bind to a port if you have no Internet connection? And what for?

Comment: @DKWGD15269 I would definitely go back to 3.4.3 for now, just for stability's sake, if nothing else. I have 3.5 on my machine, just for testing, but I use 3.4.3 for all my routine work.

Comment: @ForceBru I do not know if IDLE executes basic Python scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Assumptions:
  You're running on Windows and installed the basic python for windows (which includes idle) and probably stuck with the defaults (so you should have python in c:\python35)

Related assumptions: Windows doesn't have an out of the box loopback interface and trying to enable one is going to be more painful than working around it.

Recommendations:

1. You might want to try to sneakernet (i.e. download on a friend's computer to a USB stick and then copy over) pycharm or another IDE, but I don't know if they won't have the same problem
2. If that doesn't work, you should be able to (as an interim step while you wait for a new computer):

   1. Use Idle (with the -n flag) to edit your python program(s) [because trying to edit python programs in Wordpad is cruel], save your program as myprogram.py
   2. Open up cmd (dos prompt), cd to your save directory, do c:\python35\python.exe myprogram.py
   3. Repeat 1+2 as needed

Answer (score 0):

By using -n flag, you can use it for one time only. It means closing python idle, I'll have to redo -n flag process whenever  I want to open .